# ContextMenu with Longlistselector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, contextmenu, longlistselector

I have a longlistselector in my windows phone 8 app, where I create the source for this as:

```
List<LonglistSelectorPivot1<ChatroomslistItems>> DataSource1 = LonglistSelectorPivot1<ChatroomslistItems>.CreateGroups(pivot1source,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
            (ChatroomslistItems s) => { return s.ChatRoomName; }, true);
        pivot1List.ItemsSource = pivot1source;
```

If a person then holds the element in the list I display a ContextMenu.
The problem here is that the ContextMenu is featured in the top no matter what. I am suspecting the CreateGroups command used above. But I cannot get anything displayed without the line.

I hope to acheive that I can display the ContextMenu just above the item.